# How to handle swift classes having same name?

Tags: swift, swiftsoup

I am using swiftsoup library , in that there is Document class And I have used this to parse html documents. But in my team one of my friend created Document class for diffrent purpose.Now it is conflicting for my code after taking his pull.Is there any way to use both classes ?.
Error is "Cannot convert value of type 'Document' to specified type 'Document'"
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried doing `<LibraryName>.Document` and `<AppName>.Document`? Also, is there any specific reason you can't just rename the class in your app?

Comment: What are you suggesting?

Comment: See the answer from @matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modules are namespaces.   `SwiftSoup.Document` is not `MyApp.Document`.

Even better, use Refactor -> Rename and prevent the conflict in the first place.

Comment: Also it sounds like there is something wrong with how you’re using git. If it doesn’t compile for you, it should not have compiled for your friend.